# KDE Plasma with Walyland - Touchpad right click not working

Tags: touchpad, kde, kde-plasma-5, wayland

I've installed Debian (LMDE, Linux Mint Debian Edition) with KDE Plasma and Wayland, into Lenovo Ideapad D330 2in1 tablet/netbook. Using X11 session is not a solution, because of random blank screen when log in and rotate screen (Wayland fix this problem).

X session touchpad right click works, but in Wayland session doesn't works (left click ever)

I've found maybe is not a touchpad, is a clickpad with one button separatted by areas. https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.16.4/clickpad-softbuttons.html

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, Can you also mention how do you right-click. I mean by pressing buttons or by gestures (for example two finger tap).

Comment: Hi, by clicking at the bottom right of the touchpad. Solved installing Gnome Wayland with gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'areas' but don't know how to solve in kde plasma.